# What kind of viewcontrollers does the Dunkin Donuts app use

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a question about the [Dunkin Donuts app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dunkin-donuts/id552020897?mt=8) vs. the [Starbucks one](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/starbuc%20...%2077714?mt=8):

In DD->MyCards || Menu || Gifts

1. Form: Is that a scrollable UIViewController with 2 UIContainer viewcontrollers inside?
2. Function: buying a card is just a web server transaction but by the looks of it, it must use passbook because I don't see how it would present a purchased card?  So it must mean the purchase sends you a passbook pass.

Oh well I just saw Starbucks and noticed that you can either use passbook or the app (by flipping over the card) to present the barcode in order to scan/update the app...

Comment: Post proper functioning links

Comment: I'm kinda lost man. What is your question and is it related to programming?

Comment: Feel free to email DD if you have questions about how they implemented their app. If you have a programming question, feel free to edit your post to ask it.

Comment: Im sorry, I didnt know stackoverflow was only strictly about programming.  My question is related to programming.  My question is what kind of view controller are they using in the app.  In numeral 1 I ask "Is that a scrollable UIViewController with 2 UIContainer viewcontrollers inside?  And then there is numeral 2 which is about implementation.  Im not asking for code in either, Im asking about coding strategy or technique.  Is that frowned upon on SO?